# 'sh' environment does not respect the PATH extensions, user's local PATH not in effect?

Tags: bash, path, sh, archlinux

```
$ bl 1
$ sh -c 'bl 1'
sh: bl: command not found
```

The `bl` script is located in the user's PATH extension (`/home/user/.local/bin`) but the `sh` environment does not seem to be aware of it, the `bash` is. The main `/usr/bin/sh` executable symlinks to `/usr/bin/bash`.

Placing a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` pointing to the local `bl` script does seem to fix the issue. Expanding the PATH manually `$ PATH=/usr/bin:$HOME/.local/bin sh -c 'bl 1'` also solves it, something I don't really understand since both the bash and the sh are aware of the PATH.

```
$ export -p |grep PATH=
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:~/.local/bin"
$ sh -c 'export -p |grep PATH'
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:~/.local/bin"
```

"Something's missing and you have to find it" yet it's hard to look if you don't know what is missing.

Comment: Can you post 'PATH', and `whereis cp` so that other people understand your setup ?

Comment: Is your `PATH` variable marked to be exported? Run `export -p | grep PATH=`.

Comment: @dash-o @cbley Cp is located at `/usr/bin/cp`. The output of `export -p |grep PATH` is different for the bash and for sh; bash output: `$ export -p |grep PATH
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:~/.local/bin"` and sh output: `export -p |grep PATH
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:~/.local/bin"`.

Comment: What is your shell ? is it 'bash' or 'dash' or something else ?

Comment: That looks fine (the `/~/.local/bin` part is just a typo I suppose?!) Maybe `$HOME` does not point to the right location? Please run `sh -c 'echo $HOME'` and add the output to your question (it's really hard to read in the comments). You might also try to set the PATH manually and see if it works: `PATH=/usr/bin:$HOME/.local/bin sh -c 'bl 1'`

Comment: @dash-o @cbley sorry for the typo's, expanded the question, running under manually expanded PATH does seem to fix it. Strange because the PATH is there at bash/sh disposal (see the output of `export -p` in the question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $ export -p |grep PATH
> declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:~/.local/bin"
> ```

Having a literal `~` is wrong. It should have been expanded to `/home/user` already. The shell will expand `~` when variables are *assigned* but not when they're *expanded*.

```
$ foo=~ && echo $foo     # expanded at assignment
/home/user
$ foo='~' && echo $foo   # not expanded since the assignment is quoted
~
```

Find the [shell startup script](https://serverfault.com/a/261807/11202) where `~/.local/bin` is added to the `$PATH` and make sure `~` is not quoted.

Wrong:

```
PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin"
```

Right:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```