# Expanding the PATH with a list of directories extracted from a text file, the tilda (~) character not expanded to HOME

Tags: bash, path, sh, archlinux

The PATH is expanded by a list of directories extracted from a text file;

```
$ cat ~/.path
~/.local/bin
~/W-space/esp/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin
~/W-space/research/recognition/voxforge/bin
~/W-space/research/recognition/voxforge/bin/julius-4.3.1/bin
```

like so (The following can be found in one of the BASH's startup files):

```
declare -a BATH_ARRAY=($(cat ~/.path)) 2>/dev/null # extend path
for BATH in "${BATH_ARRAY[@]}"
do
case ":${PATH}:" in
  *:${BATH}:*) ;;
  *) PATH=${PATH}:$BATH && export PATH;;
esac
done
```

Basic iteration over the array of PATH expansion entries extracted from the `~/.path` file. The resultant PATH includes the '~' character (which is wrong hence the question):

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:~/.local/bin
```

Inside of the `~/.local/bin` there exists a `bl` script I am able to invoke, like so:

```
$ ls -l ~/.local/bin/bl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 romeo romeo 6304 Nov 17 09:06 /home/romeo/.local/bin/bl*
$ bl 1 #no error!
$
```

However some undesired effects were briefly discussed in the ['sh' environment does not respect the PATH extensions, user's local PATH not in effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912836/sh-environment-does-not-respect-the-path-extensions-users-local-path-not-in) question and include symptoms such as the following:

```
$ bl 1
$ sh -c 'bl 1'
sh: bl: command not found
$
```

```
$ bl 1
$ whereis bl
bl:
$
```

The consensus was that the '~' character should be expanded to the user's HOME before the PATH expansion. How can it be achieved, while also keeping an external file as a source of directories for the PATH expansion? Where lays the issue with the current approach? Help much appreciated :)

Comment: The `~` character is not special inside PATH. It shouldn't be expanded inside PATH.

Comment: If you read path entries from a file, and you have ~ in them, you have to handle the tilde expansion yourself before adding them to the PATH variable. Just do `${BATH/#~/$HOME}` in the assignment.

Comment: BTW, you do not have to export the variable each time you set it. Exporting it after the loop is sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Just replace `~` yourself, something like:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r BATH; do
    # also ex. readlink -m could be added to shorten the path
    case ":${PATH}:" in
        *:${BATH}:*) ;;
        *) PATH=${PATH}:$BATH ;;
    esac
done < <(sed 's~^\~~'"$HOME"'~' .path)
export PATH
```

The `~` is expanded during [tilde expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_01). The tilde `~` is then replaced by the content of the user variable `HOME`.

The shell expansions happen for example when shell interprets a line. So when a user types `echo ~` it nicely prints `echo /home/kamil`.

Tilde expansion (or any other shell expansion) doesn't happen when interpreting the `PATH` variable. How `PATH` is interpreted is specified in [POSIX environment variables 8.3](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html#tag_08_03). It has it's own rules, that are unrelated to shell expansions and unrelated to tilde expansion.

> How can it be achieved

You have to create your own shell that doesn't conform to posix and does tilde expansion when searching the PATH variable during [command search and execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01). Such shell would be nonconforming. The easiest approach would be to take bash and patch it.

A more realistic approach is just to replace the `~` in the content of your file by `$HOME` content or while reading the stream with simple `sed` replacement.

> Where lays the issue with the current approach?

The issue most probably comes from misinterpreting the way shell operates - where the expansions work.

Comment: Also there's no need to `export` anythng more than once. Chances are `PATH` will already be exported, buy maybe do it *once* just in case.

Comment: I absolutely love the 'create your own (non-conforming) shell' suggestion #thinkingoutsidethebox #sweetignorance